# Unable to get dynamic value of input ID to javascript function

Tags: javascript, laravel

Please i need help..

```
@foreach
 <input  id="mar1bags" class="form-control" name="mar1bags" value="">
@endforeach
```

I am using foreach loop to get some data and also this input field is also inside for me to input data.

But the problem now is i am unable to use GetelementbyID to get the values in javascript. it returns only for the first input field, but the others don't get.

I get this error in my console when i try to submit  to javascript function

> [DOM] Found 3 elements with non-unique id #mar1bags:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this loop create more then one input but keep setting them the same id. 
Since ID suppose to be unique it is not valid (and also the `getElementById` method would fail).

You can use the `.querySelectorAll` method instead, and the syntax is:

```
document.querySelectorAll('[property=value]');
```

EDIT to your case:

```
<script>
var hht; // declare the var GLOBAL
console.log(hht + ' before function');
function checkVal() { // make a function that will check the value
  let inputData = document.querySelectorAll('[name=mar1bags]');
  // now you can iterate inputData using a loop.
  // Using for loop will be something like this:
  for (var i=0; i < inputData.length; i++) {
    var checkEmpty = inputData[i].value.length; // get each value length
    if (checkEmpty > 0) { // if it holds more then one chareter then
      hht = inputData[i].value; // assign this to the GLOBAL
    }
  }
}
console.log(hht + ' after function');
</script>
```

Enjoy code!

Comment: thanks..let me try and get back pls...dont go anywhere my friend...can u iterate for me let me see pls

Comment: please help with the iteration let me see how u will do it pls

Comment: No problem, give me a sec

Comment: inputData[i].value. this is what i see in the console...pls help

Comment: yeah... remove the quotes (:

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205653/discussion-between-midel-group-and-a-meshu).

Answer (score 0):

as mentionned above, your id is duplicated that's why it won't work.
instead, i would do:

`@foreach
 <input  id="mar1bags-{{ $loop->iteration }}" class="form-control" name="mar1bags-{{ $loop->iteration }}" value="">
@endforeach`

```html
<script>
let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('[id^=mar1bags-]');
for (var i=0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  console.log(inputs[i].value);
}
</script>
```

Comment: This use different selector but eventually prints the same data on the demo i posted in the chat. Apparently this is not what the OP seeks. You should stay in the chat  (:

Answer (score 0):

Hey if you are using jquery or javascript to interact with this values you need to add a unique input name and ID: check answer from @erwan

or if you are using a normal form. than maybe just  change the input name to accept an array of values , so you can get all the inputs in form of an array on the backend when you submit the form.

```
@foreach
 <input  id="mar1bags" class="form-control" name="mar1bags[]" value="">
@endforeach
```